# React native mapping Checkbox to check independently

Tags: javascript, react-native

I made array with data. Then I map this and each value of array is include to specific part of mapped element. Inside of this element I created an checkbox. But When I create function that should change state of each checkbox independently. Right now when I click checkbox it change state of every checkbox (make every checkbox checked when I click one element). 
Below I put my code.

**Constructor & Function**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checked: false
    };
    this.toggle.bind(this);
}

toggle(item) {
    console.log(item);
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
}
```

**Render**

```
{today.map((item, i) => (
    <View
        key={i}
        style={{borderBottomWidth: 2,}}>
        <View style={{marginLeft: 20}}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            <View>
            {
                this.state.checked ?
                    <MaterialIcon onPress={() => this.toggle(i)}
                        id={i}
                        name="check-box" size={30}
                        color='#4AB762'/>
                :
                <MaterialIcon onPress={() => this.toggle(i)}
                    id={i}
                    name="check-box-outline-blank"
                    size={30} color='#8e8d8d'/>
            }    
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
))}
```

Comment: This happens because you have one state for all checkboxes. You have to have separate `checked` states for each checkbox

Comment: I know that I have one state to many elements but I'm not quite sure how change it. Do you have any idea or some hint for me?

Comment: just for clarify my mind: do you need to change the state only?

Comment: You could place your chekbox element in separate component with its own state.

Comment: @assembler I want to change state from false to true for clicked element right now it is changing for every element after click.

Comment: As other users has told you, you need to define a value in Component state for each checkbox, or define your own checkbox component.

Comment: @KonradUciechowski provided an example for you

Comment: Thank you that for sure will solve my problem @MikhailKatrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to solve your problem: you could place your checkbox in separate component with its own state.

Here is example below

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <CheckBox />
      <CheckBox />
      <CheckBox />
    </div>;
  }
}

class CheckBox extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        checked: false
      };
   }
   
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
  }
  
  render() {
    return <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggle} />  
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">

</div>
```

Comment: I made it with your idea and it's working thank you again!